# potential for file id collision in C when doing pthread network io

Tags: sockets, pthreads

I have an app in c that listens on a port and creates a pthread upon connection and goes back to the listen. The pthread functions reads from the socket, writes a response and then waits 1/10th of a sec followed by a shutdown() and a close() then pthread_exit(). This can happen very rapidly resulting in possibly hundreds of threads at the same time. My question is can the system reuse a file id before I do the final close()? I'm concerned about the possibility of the socket closing prematurely for some reason. On the listening side the file id cannot be reused until I do the close() call even if the underlying connection is long gone, right? I'm fairly sure that this is how it works but I can't confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the listening side the file id cannot be reused until I do the
>   `close()` call even if the underlying connection is long gone, right?

Yes, this is correct - the file descriptor is not released for re-use until it has been passed to `close()` (or is an `FD_CLOEXEC` file descriptor being closed automatically at `execve()`).

Answer (score 0):

All thread try to enter critical region to be processed if you didn't use semafor,mutex or monitoring probably it uses same id even your files that you get from byte stream may be croupted. I advise to you use semafor, mutex ,or monitoring, and search about [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem), because it is very frequent situation. Good luck I hope I can show a clue about your problem.